# I get error: module 'tensorflow.keras.layers' has no attribute 'Normalization'

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I use

```
layers.Normalization()
```

in Keras, in `keras.Sequential`
When I try to run it, I get the following error:

> module 'tensorflow.keras.layers' has no attribute 'Normalization'

I've seen the command `layers.Normalization()` being used in many codes, so I don't know what's wrong. Did something change?

Comment: Are you sure the layer is called Normalization? Because I think there is no layer with that name. But there is BatchNormalization and LayerNormalization.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy check it out here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Normalization

Comment: Great, in that link, do you see this?  TensorFlow  API  TensorFlow Core v2.6.0 Python, you need TF 2.6 for this code to work.

Comment: I'm trying to replicate the code found here: https://github.com/keras-team/keras-io/blob/master/examples/vision/image_classification_with_vision_transformer.py
and it says that it requires 2.4.0 or higher, so I assumed it must work with my version, which is 2.4.0.
EDIT: I just upgraded the version and it seems to work fine, so thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the version of TensorFlow you have:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
```

`tf.keras.layers.Normalization` is an attribute in TensorFlow v2.6.0, so might not work on earlier versions: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Normalization

If you have an earlier version, you can upgrade using

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

Comment: Hi, the tensorflow version I have is 2.4.0

Comment: The docs are for v2.6.0. I don't know exactly when tf.keras.layers.Normalization was introduced. Maybe try updating to the latest version and retry?

Comment: Just did and it worked fine. It's just that the code I'm trying to replicate (link in the comments below the question) was using version 2.4.0 so I don't know what happened there. In any case, thank you!

Comment: If you add to your answer that you need 2.6.0, I'll accept it so that future users can see the solution clearly

Comment: tf.keras.layers.Normalization does not work in v2.6.0 either. I just tried after updating and still doesn't work for me

Comment: I had to run `pip.exe install tensorflow==2.6 --user` then it updated. Thanks

Answer (score 16):

One reason can be that you are using the tensorflow version older then the required to use that layer. There are two ways to get around this problem.

1. Upgrade tensorflow as discussed above.
2. Or you can add the layer  as follows:

```
tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Normalization
```

Regards