# Getting error: module 'tensorflow.keras.layers' has no attribute 'Normalization'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using

```
tf.keras.layers.Normalization(axis=-1)
```

and am getting the following error:

```
module 'tensorflow.keras.layers' has no attribute 'Normalization'
```

I'm following the tensorflow tutorial available [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/regression). I went through the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69470332/i-get-error-module-tensorflow-keras-layers-has-no-attribute-normalization) and updated my tensorflow to v2.6.0. But still getting the error. I am new to tensorflow. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The tutorial you linked uses `v2.8.0-rc1`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However,the solution I mentioned also uses 'tf.keras.layers.Normalization()' and the reply suggests that the issue was resolved with an update to v2.6.0. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not sure, but is anything preventing you from upgrading into the latest version?

Comment: No. As I mentioned I just began using tensorflow and setting up the packages the way I want has been a headache till now. I will try to update it. Also, `tf.keras.layers.Normalization()` can be seen in the v2.6.0 documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.6/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Normalization)

Comment: I am working with conda and as it appears, the latest version of tensorflow supported by conda is v2.6.0. So, Is there any way to install tensorflow 2.8?

Comment: Have you verified via `tf.__version__` _inside the script you are trying to run_ that it's indeed using 2.6? It might be an issue with environments. As for installing 2.8, I guess the answer would be "don't use conda" or wait until they provide the new version. You can also try replacing the call by `tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Normalization` which was the old name of this layer.

Comment: Hi @xdurch0, yes I have verified the version and it is indeed 2.6.0. I finally installed 2.8.0. However, when I try to use GPU, it is not detected. It was detected earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who may be looking for answer, I ditched Anconda altogether and set up everything from scratch. Thanks for all the responses.